# Abstract away autofaccontainer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have created an IDependencyContainer interface which abstracts away the logic behind IOC and should allow me to switch IOC frameworks.  Currently I use Autofac.

I also inject this IDependencyContainer container itself in autofac because I have some places where I need to use the container directly.  Occasionaly I now get the error that my container has already been disposed or that my webrequest scope is not available.

Is there any easy way to register the autofac container into itself?

Comment: you have to create a new child container at the beginning of every request and dispose of it at the end of every request.  You shouldn't be requesting from the main container.  Let me verify what I have in my project and I can get back to you tonight or tomorrow.

Comment: Your question indicates that you are applying the Service Locator anti-pattern in your application. Please try to understand [why this is an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) and if possible, move away from this and use dependency injection instead.

Comment: I have to agree with @Steven here, abstracting away Autofac shouldn't imply that you have to use the container directly.  If done correctly your IoC abstraction should simply expose a few methods to register a type/implement against the underlying Autofac container

Answer (score 0):

I know service locator is considered bad practice however in this case i don't think that applies! I have build a controller mediator that gets injecties into my mvc controllers! This mediator then requests the container for the appropriate handler of this request/response combination! I don't know how to otherwise abstract away this logic without injecting my container!